# Problems Making DevExpress SimpleButton Visible At Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am working on a C# WinForms application that uses some DevExpress controls.  I am struggling to figure out why I cannot make a hidden SimpleButton visible at runtime by setting its' Visible property to true.  I've attempted to give the control focus, refresh the control, refresh the form to no avail.  One thing that I have noticed in the debugger is that after the statement btnAddJob.Visible = true, the Visible property is still false.  Any ideas?

```
    public AddPredefinedJobsForm(WorkOrder workOrder)
        : this()
    {
        currentWorkOrder = workOrder;
        // Here I am just getting the position to display the button
        btnAddJob.Location = new Point(btnNewJob.Location.X, btnNewJob.Location.Y);
        // Hiding the button that my hidden button will replace below
        btnNewJob.Visible = false;
        // Give my hidden button focus
        btnAddJob.Focus();
        // Make my hidden button Visible
        btnAddJob.Visible = true;
        // Refresh the button
        btnAddJob.Refresh();

        // Refresh the entire form
        this.Refresh();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the button inside of a container control (like a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)), you'll need to set the container's visibility to `True` in order for its child controls to be visible.

Comment: Thanks, I'm such a newbie.  That did the trick.  The button was inside of a groupControl which explains the behavior I was experiencing.